# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 (Runtime Exception)

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter, dart

while starting a flutter application on vs code i am getting the following errors.

> Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1801 in debug mode...
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\sanjay.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   [!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\sanjay.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   [!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
>   Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
>   Exited (sigterm)

I am not getting why this is occurring . What can be the reason for this and how can this be solved?

Comment: from github issues seems like a slow internet connection,you can find the issues at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45037

Comment: Hi, if my answer solve your issue can you pls mark it as correct? tks!

Comment: closed the project and restarted it, error gone. I guess it because of slow internet

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is caused by the Gradle distribution version used. To fix this, either downgrade your Gradle version to the previous or upgrade it to the next stable one. These are the [Gradle distribution](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) versions available.

Go to

> android / gradle / wrapper / gradle-wrapper.properties

and replace the current Gradle version this  (or choose another from [Gradle distribution](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/))

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip

[image: screenshot]

I upgraded my Gradle version from 5.6.2 to 6.0.1, and it works fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing a similar problem. The following worked for me !

C:\Users\uejaz.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb
Move to this directory and delete gradle-5.6.2-all.zip and gradle-5.6.2 folder

Goto https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip and download the zip file
Replace the .zip file with the one you had deleted earlier and extract the folder "gradle-5.6.2" in the same directory. I hope it will solve all your gradle-related problems.

Note: if your gradle version is different than mine, just change the version in the link provided above to download your gradle version.

Comment: Same as @usama one thing that really worked for me is to go to Android folder -> gradle.build and change gradle version there

Answer (score 2):

For VS Code. if All answers are not working. do this.

I was finally able to solve the problem. The problem is with the gradle and low internet bandwidth.
Just delete the C:\Users\USERNAME.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all
and download it manually from [https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip] or delete the old gradle files and let them download manually by using flutter run Be sure to check your gradle version before proceeding.

Comment: Somehow i am not able to delete gradle as it says some apps are using it. Can u please look into that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by upgrading the Gradle version.

Just go to:

```
android > grader\wrapper > Gradle-wrapper.properties
```

and then replace the current Gradle version to the new one:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

You can see the Gradle versions in this page: https://gradle.org/releases

Answer (score 1):

The steps worked for me are as follows

1. Go to wrapper file in android
2. Delete 'gradle' file inside wrapper file
3. Then delete 'gradlew' file
4. Go to 'gradle-wrapper.properties'
5. Replace distributionUrl with belo link
   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
6. Exit from android studio and re-open

Hope this would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Open the flutter projects's android directory from Android Studio . It will automatically shows you to delete old gradle version and update to current version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal
2. Go to project directory
3. Run Below command

> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

> flutter run

This solved my problem.