# how to resolve "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1"?

Tags: flutter, gradle

how to resolve errors when installing flutter"Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1" ?

Comment: provide logs and code

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. You need to update the Gradle Distribution.

Go to

```
android > grader\wrapper > Gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Replace the gradle distribution to a new version. You can download it here: https://gradle.org/releases/

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip
```

Please click this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573809/13446466. They helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple.

Make sure your DNS Resolver config file is writable:

Open Terminal.

Type : sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

Change the IP address in the file to: 8.8.8.8

Press CTRL+X to save the file.

Now you run flutter.

(OR)

delete .grade folder,And run flutter.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R00Dr.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).