# Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, android-gradle-plugin

I just setup my flutter in android studio but whenever i am creating new project an running it shows me this : "Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"
Below is the snapshot of console log please anyone help i am new to flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J700F in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         0.6s
    [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         0.3s
    [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Do follow some steps:

Go to flutter_app => android => gradle => wrapper directory

Delete gradle-wrapper.jar file

Open and edit gradle-wrapper.properties file

Change distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-5.6.2-all.zip or latest

On terminal use flutter run command

Comment: you can also check the answers here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316518/gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-runtime-exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'D:\neyaz1\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:64)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:47)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:60)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip 
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)

Comment: did you only change the gradle-x.x.x-all.zip to gradle-5.6.2-all.zip in the previous code?

Comment: No, first delete the gradle-wrapper.jar file then chnge the distribution but it shows that error which is i write in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i also have the same issues ,this may due to corrupt in your gradel files so
try the following steps it have worked for me,

Go to,

C->user->(username)->.gradle
delete the .gradle file and run then run your flutter project
once re-run your project it will create new .gradle folder correctly,

hope it will work...