# When I add hive package to my project I got errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

for using data in clients I added a hive package to my project

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^2.3.0
```

after the pub and running debug I got this error
**
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:classpath'.
> Could not find builder-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
> Could not find protos-26.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.3.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.3.0/protos-26.3.0.jar
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> 2
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
**

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.3.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision eb6d86ee27 (8 days ago) • 2022-10-04 22:31:45 -0700
Engine • revision c08d7d5efc
Tools • Dart 2.18.2 • DevTools 2.15.0**

flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.2006], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.0.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.72.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Also, I downloaded **protos-26.3.0.jar** and **builder-3.3.0.jar** and run these files but it did not happen.
what I missed?

Comment: Run ```Flutter doctor``` see the  issue and what is the version of gradle you are using?

Comment: I added flutter doctor result

Comment: As you cna refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316518/gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-runtime-exception) the version of gradle might be incompatible, you can see app->gradle.build file.

Comment: Try to add path_provider as a dependency. If you did, remove any version number and keep it empty.

Answer (score 0):

maybe hive_flutter is an older project and not the updated one,
remove hive_flutter try to Go with hive only.